# mongodb query pushing by python script

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

my database structure in mongodb is as

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9fef05c0228a50befba0d7"),
        "name" : "sanghm",
        "id" : "3456",
        "dep" : {
                "dep1" : "ops",
                "dep2" : "analytics"
        },
        "data" : [
                {
                        "date" : "25-apr-2020",
                        "log" : [

                                {
                                        "machine" : "windows-user1",
                                        "task" : "excel",
                                          "time": "10:00am"
                                }
                                {
                                        "machine" : "windows-user1",
                                        "task" : "email",
                                          "time": "11:00am"
                                }

                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

i want to write a python script which keep on add data to the database, so for an user data>date>log array keep adding the new entry on every user activity.In mongodb shell i can write the query as

```
db.inventory.update({id:3456},{$push:{'data.$[t].log':{machine:'windows-user1',task:'personal', time:'12:30pm'}}},{arrayFilters:[{"t.date":'25-apr-2020'}]})
```

this query works in mongodb shell but same thing i want to send via python script to update/add in "log".
I have tried a query by using pymongo library but it gives error

```
myclient= myclient()
db=myclient['example']
collecton = db['inventory']
recieved = collection.update_one({id:3456},{$push:{'data.$[t].log':{machine:'windows-user1',task:'personal', time:'12:30pm'}}},{arrayFilters:[{"t.date":'25-apr-2020'}]})
```

any solution!!! please

Answer (score 0):

The snytax for pymongo is just a tad different, try this:

```
recieved = collection.update_one(
    {
        "id": 3456
    },
    {
        "$push": {
            'data.$[t].log': {
                "machine": 'windows-user1',
                "task": 'personal',
                "time": '12:30pm'
            },
        }
    },
    array_filters=[
        {"t.date": '25-apr-2020'}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hi, if {"t.date": '25-apr-2020'} does not exist in data base then can we insert new entry by adding {upsert:true} in same query.